# How to use algolia places in React?

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I would like to use Algolia places to populate a country select input in a React app. I've installed algoliasearch, but typescript claims that:

> initPlaces is not a function

Here is what I wrote. How to fix this?

```js
const placesClient = algoliasearch.initPlaces({
  appId: 'myAppId',
  apiKey: 'myAPIKey'
});

export default function App() {
const [data, setData]= useState("")
const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
  useEffect(()=> {
    placesClient.search({
      query,
      type: 'country'
    })
    .then(res=> setData(res.data))
    .catch(_=> null)
  },[])
  return (
     <input placeholder="search country" type="text" onChange={(e)=> setQuery(e.target.value)}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you imported Algolia? ``import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';``

Comment: Which version of the Algolia client are you using? The version 4.x.x doesn't support Algolia Places out of the box anymore. You can find more information / alternatives in the documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/upgrade-guides/javascript/#the-initplaces-method.